# Typo3 plugin not working in draft-workspace

Tags: plugins, typo3

I have a selfmade T3-plugin that actually works fine.
*Unless* I try to look at it in the draft-workspace - then I get an error saying «Template could not be found at "typo3/sysext/workspaces/Resources/Private/Templates/Preview/Preview.html"» (of course, the template *is* there).
We're working with T3 6.1.8
There were some rollbacks made recently that might have caused this, but that's just a wild guess...

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was actually quite trivial.
The person who wrote the extension used chdir() in the extension's header to write a PDF file. This confused the workspaces plugin so it didn't find it's own directory anymore.

Comment: Please consider to either mark the question as answered or close it completely since it was rather a very specific scenario and programming flaw